# on/along do both mean the same here?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> 1. My queen and king were **along** the same line. Which is how I lost my queen, the most powerful piece in the game.
> 2. My queen and king were **on** the same line. Which is how I lost my queen, the most powerful piece in the game.

Do both the sentences mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use along here. They are **on** the same line.

*Along the same lines* is an idiom for doing more or less the same thing as someone else: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/along-the-same-lines